# iPhone producing strange results on 'if' statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIPicker where the user inputs a specified time (i.e. 13:00, 13:01, 13:02, etc.) - which determines their score.  Once they hit the button an alert comes up with the score that is determined through this 'if-else' statement.  Everything seems to work great MOST of the time - but I am getting some erratic behavior.  This is the code:

```
    //Gets my value from the UIPicker and then converts it into a format that can be used in the 'if' statement.    
    NSInteger runRow = [runTimePicker selectedRowInComponent:2];
    NSString *runSelected = [runTimePickerData objectAtIndex:runRow];
    NSString *runSelectedFixed = [runSelected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"."];

    //The actual 'if' statment.
    if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.00) {
    runScore = 100;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.06) {
    runScore = 99;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.12) {
    runScore = 97;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.18) {
    runScore = 96;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.24) {
    runScore = 94;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.30) {
    runScore = 93;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.36) {
    runScore = 92;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.42) {
    runScore = 90;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.48) {
    runScore = 89;
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.54) {
    runScore = 88;
}
```

Now, when I test the program, I will get the expected result when I choose '13:00' which is '100'.  I also get the expected result of '99' when I choose all of the times between '13:01 and 13:05'.  BUT, when I choose '13:06' it gives me a score of '97'.  I also get a score of '97' on '13:07 through 13:12' - which is the desired result.  Why would I get a '97' right on '13:12' but not get a '99' right on '13:06'????  Could this be a memory leak or something???

Comment: Have you tried logging `[runSelectedFixed floatValue]`? Chances are your float isn't *exactly* 13.06, but slightly more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you instead convert it to an integer? 
e.g.

```
NSString *runSelectedFixed = [runSelected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
```

..

Answer (score 4):

No, not a memory leak, but a fundamental aspect of how floating point numbers work. Not every rational number can be represented accurately by a float. Some numbers are more accurate than others. It is well documented [else where](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

You would be better off splitting the time into integer hours and minutes..

```
NSArray *components = [@"13:42" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]
int hrs = [[components objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int mins = [[components objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a raw floating point number in your source code, it is assumed to be a `double`. When you compare this to `[runSelectedFixed floatValue]`, which is a `float` type, the compiler must first cast your `float` to a `double` and then do the comparison.

Because floating point numbers cannot perfectly represent all base-10 numbers, your values are internally rounded to the nearest floating-point representation. For example, when you enter `13.06` the `float` representation may actually be `13.058` (Just a theoretical example, you actually have more precision than this). Since a `double` has more precision, it may hold `13.059` when you enter `13.06`. Thus, once you compare the two you won't always get the result you expect. Be sure to read [the Wikipedia article on floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) so you understand the limitations and proper use of floating point code.

You can make all of the floating point numbers in your code above `float` literals by adding an `f` to the end of each one. For example:

```
} else if ([runSelectedFixed floatValue] <= 13.06f) {
```

This will keep all of your numbers to the same precision and help avoid the issue you're seeing above. However, you should not use a 100-line if-else block at accomplish what could be done with a simple equation:

```
int runScore = 100 - (int)(([runSelectedFixed floatValue] - 13.0f) / 0.06f);
```

Add bounds checked as appropriate for your code. Also consider splitting runSelectedFixed into hrs and minutes components first as mustISignUp suggested.

Answer (score 0):

How are you converting times (13:06) to floats (13.06)?  6/60ths =0.1, which would lead to the results you are seeing.  I'd guess this is the real cause, but a good solution would be the same as suggested by @mustISignUp.